# Use components to simplify long HTML, even if components don't repeat and have no props (Vue or any other js library). Yes or No?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, components

In team Vue.js project I'm curently working, I wrote something like this in view:

component01
component02
...

There is more than 10 componenets. In every component is one section of landing page, nothing fancy, mostly HTML/CSS and some animations, components don't have props and are used only once. Idea is to simplify maintenance of code - instead of editing view page with, for example, 1000 lines of code, we can edit component with 100 lines of code.

And got instructions to merge all components into one view (eg. 1000 or more lines of code). I'm OK with that, but got me thinking and searching for opinions.

Is there best practice for situations like this - use components even if there is no repeating and no props, to simplify code, or hold everything in one view (and long) file. Components can be in separate folders, so big number of components should not be a problem. Or will they?

Comment: 1000 lines of code in a web page doesn't bother me.  10,000 lines does, which is what we had originally in our Vue applications, because they were literally "single-page."  Our pages routinely contain 1000 lines of code, and it's not a problem.

Comment: As with most decisions in software development, this is an exercise in tradeoffs.  Determine which tradeoffs are most important to you, and make your decision on that basis.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wrote 1000 as example, but small number maybe empasize even more the point. What is bodering me is that I can not think of a single downside of "componitaze" in this way, even for a single landing page of average size.

Comment: Just more components and additional complexity, that's all.   No technique is entirely cost-free.

Comment: "Small just for the sake of being small" doesn't seem like a well thought-out strategy.  However, try watching [this talk by Gary Bernhardt,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57lwoBpfrgk) where he talks about the ["Squish Principle"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/418252/java-splitting-a-large-unit-test-class#comment919938_418252).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components are the building blocks of all modern JavaScript frameworks as they provide a better overall architecture for your application in terms of reusability, testability, maintainability and in the end SOLID and KISS principles.

I would recommend splitting your app in smaller and presentational components and use services for business logic. It does not matter if the application is small, by following these principles it will be able to grow with no or less pain. That is the way Angular encourages you to build applications.

As always in this industry, don't overuse these concepts and apply where appropriate and with common sense ;-)

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I was trying not to be too much bias (i sad "too much" ;) ) in my question. Thanks for this!!!